# AssemblyResolve not fired with anonymous handler

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, assemblyresolve

I'm trying to resolve dynamically loaded assemblies, but the AssemblyResolve event does not appear to work with anonymous functions.

```
private void Load() {
    ResolveEventHandler resolve = (sender, args) => Assembly.LoadFile(pathToDependency);

    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += resolve;
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += this._AssemblyResolve;
    Assembly.LoadFile(pathToDll);
}

private void _AssemblyResolve(Object sender, ResolveEventArgs args) {
    return Assembly.LoadFile(pathToDependency);
}
```

`this._AssemblyResolve` and `resolve` are virtually the same function, except that the anonymous `resolve` function creates a closure that uses a variable defined in the `Load` method.

For some reason, `this._AssemblyResolve` gets called, but `resolve` doesn't. Why?

I can't really rely on the `_AssemblyResolve` method because the method needs to know about a variable that is defined in the `Load` method. I can use a workaround, but I still don't understand why the anonymous function doesn't work.

Comment: What if you remove `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += this._AssemblyResolve;` and leave only anon handler?

Comment: @Evk Same issue

Comment: Then not sure, for me anonymous handler fires just fine

Comment: Maybe you can create minimal reproducable example?

Comment: My crystal ball says that you are simply confused by the debugger.  Like setting a breakpoint on the assignment statement instead of the lambda expression.